# GPPSignInButton has no Text

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-signin

I am making a sample to login using Google+ and by reading this documentation : https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in, the integration works but the sign-in button has no text. and Ive already subclass it in storyboard from `GPPSignInButton`

In my `viewDidLoad` method i defined the following:

```
GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = YES;
signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;  // Uncomment to get the user's email
signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserID = YES;

// You previously set kClientId in the "Initialize the Google+ client" step
signIn.clientID = kClientId;

// Uncomment one of these two statements for the scope you chose in the previous step
signIn.scopes = @[ kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin ];  // "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login" scope
//signIn.scopes = @[ @"profile" ];
// "profile" scope

// Optional: declare signIn.actions, see "app activities"
signIn.delegate = self;
```

[image]

Comment: Did you add the `GooglePlus.bundle` to your project (in addition to the `.framework`)?

Comment: i did pod `"google-plus-ios-sdk"` and pod `'Google/SignIn'`. i think that contains GooglePlus.bundle !

Comment: @NataMio How you subclass the GPPSignInButton???

Comment: in storyboard, where you give the custom class for a button instead of `UIButton`